# MediaPlayer. Cannot use this in a static context

Tags: java, static, android-mediaplayer

I have a method which is to be static.
But have a problem.

> Cannot use **this** in a static context

```
static void nextTrackWin(int i) {   
        mWinner = new int [] {
                R.raw.win_one, 
                R.raw.win_two, 
                R.raw.win_three
                };
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, mWinner[i % 3]);
        mp.start();
        }
```

How to fix?

Comment: `this` is a reference to the current object. static is a context which is independent of any given object. You cannot reference `this` from a static context because there is no `this`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `this` in a static method. `this` is representing the object the code is currently running in. But your method is static and therefore not running in any object. So you have no access to `this`. Basically you'll have to replace the `this` by some argument in the argumentlist of nextTrackWin.